# How to refresh all children being iteration over in the parent lighting web component

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I have a parent that has a for each that iterates over a child component. When i change the data in the form and hit save. It triggers apex refresh. In the screen shot you will see one child highlighted, if i save the form data it will trigger the refresh that data. If i save the form data for the non highlighted child it won't refresh that children's data.

[image]

On the parent Js i have a method that is called to refresh the parent and also send a method to the chid to refresh.

Parent.Js

```
      onParentRefresh(){
        this.template.querySelector("c-project-Power-Construction").handlePowerConstRefresh();
        
      }
```

Child.js

```
import { LightningElement,wire,api,track } from 'lwc';
import getProjectPowerConst from '@salesforce/apex/projectPowerConstClass.getProjectPowerConst';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';


export default class ProjectPowerConstruction extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement){
    @api getPowerConstId;
    @track hideRow = false;
     newProjectConstSummary;
   @track projectPowerConstData;
    selected;
    listenerAttached = false;
    testArray = [];
    @api rowhighlighted;

    @wire(getProjectPowerConst, {parentPower: '$getPowerConstId'})

    projectPowerConstsHandler(response){
        
       
        let data = response.data;
        let error = response.error;

        if(data){
                this.projectResponse = response;
                console.log(this.projectResponse);
                this.projectPowerConstData = data;
          
        }
        if(error){
            console.log('error');
        }

    }



    @api handlePowerConstRefresh(){
        console.log(this.projectResponse);
        return refreshApex(this.projectResponse);


    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the save button? In the parent component or in child one? Do you want to update every child, no matter which is highlighted, or only the highlighted ones?

Comment: the save button is on a different child, that is a pop out. The save button on the different child fires to refresh the parent. When the parent Refresh i want it to refresh all the children that are on the parent page. Even the non highlighted ones. Right now it only refresh the highlighted one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`querySelector()` returns the first element within the document that matches the specified selector.
Since you need to refresh every child and `onParentRefresh` is already called on save button, you could use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) then loop over the returned list and call `handlePowerConstRefresh()` on each child.

```js
onParentRefresh(){
    const childList = this.template.querySelectorAll("c-project-power-construction");
    childList.forEach((childElem) => {
        childElem.handlePowerConstRefresh();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked